# install cab file (Edge WebView2) via Powershell/cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd, webview2, cab

I want to install Edge WebView2 Runtime **FixedVersion** with a cab file:
Microsoft.WebView2.FixedVersionRuntime.100.0.1185.50.x64.cab

How can I install WebView2 Runtime with this cab file via Powershell/cmd?

I've tried

```
dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Temp\Microsoft.WebView2.FixedVersionRuntime.100.0.1185.39.x64.cab" /quiet /norestart
```

I've copied the file to C:\Temp but when I try to execude this code, it says "the system cannot find the file specified"

What am I doing wrong?

BR

Comment: Check out the powershell command `Add-WindowsPackage`.

Comment: You typed 100.0.1185.39.x64.cab instead of 100.0.1185.50.x64.cab

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to install a WebView2 Runtime Fixed Version cab. You can just expand it to any new folder you like. To expand a Fixed Version cab you run the following:

```
expand {path to the package} -F:* {path to the destination folder}
```

So in your case:

```
expand C:\Temp\Microsoft.WebView2.FixedVersionRuntime.100.0.1185.39.x64.cab -F:* C:\Temp\
```

This will result in a new folder `C:\Temp\Microsoft.WebView2.FixedVersionRuntime.100.0.1185.39.x64` containing the directory structure stored in the cab.

See [Details about the Fixed Version runtime distribution mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#:%7E:text=recently%20added%20APIs.-,Details%20about%20the%20Fixed%20Version%20runtime%20distribution%20mode,-For%20constrained%20environments).

Comment: I need the fixed version to be the default version on the system, replacing the current dynamically installed version. E.g. to be used with he new MS Teams.